# Origin of image in jquery animation (height and width)

Tags: jquery, image, animation, user-interface

working on another site, and find a problem I cant figure out

I have a picture inside a div. on click I use animate(width, height).
Problem is that effect working from top left corner, but I need it to work from bottom middle.

Search the web, but without a luck.

It's must be a simple task, but I cannot figure it out.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexela/7gk8D/)

Thanks in advance
Alexei

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<style>

#prof_window{
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
    outline: 1px solid #808080;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 85px;
    width: 1072px;
    background-color: rgba(100, 200, 11, 0.7);
}

#prof_div{
    height: 300px;
    outline: 1px solid #808080;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1200px;
}

.profi{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 60px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url(images/home_layer1.png);
    border: 8px solid;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    bottom: -100px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="prof_window">
    <div id="prof_div">
        <div class="profi"><img src="http://www.luxmed.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Дан-Флис.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="profi"><img src="http://www.luxmed.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Дан-Флис.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="profi"><img src="http://www.luxmed.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Дан-Флис.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="profi"><img src="http://www.luxmed.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Дан-Флис.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.profi').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({width: '100px', height: '100px'});
    });
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any other solution??? Please help. Still searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/6N9EH/2/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.profi').click(function() {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            width: "-=40",
            height: "-=60",
            top: "+=20",
            left: "+=20"
        }, 300);
    });
})
</script>
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.

Comment: Dont be, it's working, but I think there MUST be better way. Anyway, big thanks! )